# find AVG in Sqlite by ignoring null/empty value

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

Here is my database

| id | mark |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 80 |

my code :

```
SELECT id as dd,AVG(mark) as avg 
FROM  Mark_O 
WHERE mark IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY id
```

Output

| id | mark |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 70 |

How can i get this

| id | mark |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 70 |

Comment: what has this to do with java?

Comment: WHERE mark IS NOT NULL   AND mark<>' '

Comment: Are you sure that blank cell is not a 0 (zero) value, and it is the rendering of the cell that is the issue? Try `WHERE mark <> 0`. --- Or, as Sergey is suggesting, the value is an empty string, not a number. But why would you be doing `AVG()` on a non-numeric column, so that can't be it, can it?

Comment: The joys of SQLite's weird (not to say broken) data type handling... This works as expected in essentially all other databases, e.g. Postgres https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=45de68c579552158bbd3c6c72e8bbcda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the `WHERE` clause.  One simple method is:

```
SELECT id as dd,AVG(mark) as avg 
FROM  Mark_O 
WHERE mark > 0
GROUP BY id;
```

This does not allow explicitly `'0'` marks, though.  If you want to allow that, then you need to know what the "missing" values are.  If it is the empty string:

```
SELECT id as dd,AVG(mark) as avg 
FROM  Mark_O 
WHERE mark <> ''
GROUP BY id;
```

Note that both of these conditions also filter out `NULL` rows.  However, they would not be counted for the `AVG()` anyway.

Comment: @Mohamed don't keep blank values in the table. Update the table and replace all of them with nulls. If you don't then in every aggregation query you must add conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` by default ignores `NULL`s, so if the empty/blank value of `mark` was `NULL` your code would work as expected.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=663f5cb07e628061b85e445285805f48).

So, that empty/blankvalue is either `''` or contains spaces and SQLite implicitly converts it to `0` when it performs numeric calculations and when used in aggregate functions like `AVG()`.

The best thing to do is update your table so these empty/blank values are replaced with `NULL`s:

```
UPDATE Mark_O
SET mark = NULL
WHERE TRIM(mark) = ''
```

Then you can use your code without the condition `WHERE mark IS NOT NULL`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d20886320bdf010f465c8889191aea4c).